# Error About Deployment of Flink on Yarn

Tags: apache-flink

I tried to deploy Flink on Yarn, but failed. It seemed that Yarn could not launch container. Anyone kowns this problem? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

When i start Flink like this:

```
[admin@bufer108072.tbc ~/flink-0.10-SNAPSHOT]$ bin/yarn-session.sh -n 4
```

I get the following console print out:

```
09:16:35,069 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster                        - Start application client.
Flink JobManager is now running on bufer108132.tbc:34408
JobManager Web Interface: http://bufer108072.tbc.tbsite.net:18088/proxy/application_1429189812285_269263/
New messages from the YARN cluster:
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:35 CST 2015] Launching container 0 (container_1429189812285_269263_01_000003 on host bufer108093.tbc).
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:35 CST 2015] Launching container 1 (container_1429189812285_269263_01_000004 on host bufer108133.tbc).
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:37 CST 2015] Launching container 2 (container_1429189812285_269263_01_000006 on host bufer108115.tbc).
New messages from the YARN cluster:
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:38 CST 2015] Launching container 3 (container_1429189812285_269263_01_000007 on host bufer108115.tbc).
New messages from the YARN cluster:
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:43 CST 2015] Diagnostics for containerID=container_1429189812285_269263_01_000003 in state=COMPLETE.
Exception from container-launch:

    org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:511)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:424)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:656)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:279)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

main : command provided 1
main : user is yarn
main : requested yarn user is admin

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

New messages from the YARN cluster:
[Mon Aug 03 09:16:44 CST 2015] Launching container 4 (container_1429189812285_269263_01_000009 on host bufer108066.tbc).
09:16:49,663 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Remote JobManager has been stopped successfully. Stopping local application client
09:16:49,668 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Stopped Application client.
09:16:49,681 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Shutting down remote daemon.
09:16:49,683 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
09:16:49,714 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator         - Remoting shut down.
09:16:49,739 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster                        - Application application_1429189812285_269263 finished with state FINISHED and final state FAILED at 1438564609501
09:16:50,118 WARN  org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli                   - Exception while running the interactive command line interface

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get Cluster status from Application Client
            at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster.getClusterStatus(FlinkYarnCluster.java:278)
            at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli.runInteractiveCli(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:294)
            at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli.run(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:445)
            at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli.main(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:344)

Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://flink/user/applicationClient#1824625362]] had already been terminated.
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:132)
        at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.$qmark$extension(AskSupport.scala:144)
        at akka.pattern.AskSupport$class.ask(AskSupport.scala:75)
        at akka.pattern.package$.ask(package.scala:43)
        at akka.pattern.Patterns$.ask(Patterns.scala:47)
        at akka.pattern.Patterns.ask(Patterns.scala)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster.getClusterStatus(FlinkYarnCluster.java:273)
        ... 3 more
09:16:50,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli                   - Command Line Interface requested session shutdown
09:16:50,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster                        - Sending shutdown request to the Application Master
09:16:50,121 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster                        - Deleting files in hdfs://bufer108072.tbc:9000/user/admin/.flink/application_1429189812285_269263
09:16:51,093 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnCluster                        - YARN Client is shutting down
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the `LinuxContainerExecutor`. I'm not sure how well Flink is tested with that executor.
Is this a production environment or a testing environment? Are other applications (MapReduce, Spark, ...) running on the setup?

Comment: It's testing environment but the configurations are similar to product environment. I looked up the yarn-site.xml but didn't find the configuration item about LinuxContainerExecutor. And other MapReduce application works well in testing environment. @rmetzger

Comment: This is a similar issue: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Issue-on-running-spark-application-in-Yarn-cluster-mode/td-p/19830
Can you try to get the log for the application: `yarn logs -applicationId application_1429189812285_269263`. Maybe it contains something helpful.
This user reports that the classpath has been wrong: http://answers.mapr.com/questions/161768/mapreduce-job-failed-exited-with-exitcode-1-1.html (here as well: http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/129nvx5tne/linuxcontainerexecutor-in-secure-mode)