# Error with Kerberos authentication when executing Flink example code on YARN cluster (Cloudera)

Tags: apache-flink

I was trying Flink on YARN cluster to run the example code (flink*examples*WordCount.jar) but am getting the below security authentication error.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (CsvOutputFormat (path: hdfs://10.94.146.126:8020/user/qawsbtch/flink_out, delimiter:  ))': SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

I am not sure where the issue is and what is that I am missing to do. I could run spark or map-reduce jobs without any issue in the same cloudera hadoop cluster.

I did update the CONF file paths for hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml in the flink-conf.yaml (updated same in Master and Worker nodes) and also export the HADOOP_CONF_DIR path. Also I tried give the host:port in the HDFS file path when executing flink run command.

ERROR MESSAGE

```
    22:14:25,138 ERROR   org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend                           - Error while running the command.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (CsvOutputFormat (path: hdfs://10.94.146.126:8020/user/qawsbtch/flink_out, delimiter:  ))': SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:356)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:349)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:63)
        at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:437)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:353)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:315)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:584)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:290)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.run(CliFrontend.java:873)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.run(CliFrontend.java:870)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityUtils$1.run(SecurityUtils.java:50)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityUtils.runSecured(SecurityUtils.java:47)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:870)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:922)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (CsvOutputFormat (path: hdfs://10.94.146.126:8020/user/qawsbtch/flink_out, delimiter:  ))': SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?
I suspect Flink can not access HDFS, but I would like to see the exact call where the problem is happening.

Comment: @rmetzger Thanks for your

Comment: @rmetzger
The log contents is much bigger than it can fit in the response comment section here which allows only about 600 characters.. so how do i send the entire log?

Comment: Can you post it using a GitHub gist https://gist.github.com/ ?

Comment: @rmetzger
https://gist.github.com/Aravind-Thaipulley/68d43f20a06290ddec46

Comment: Great, thank you.
I'm trying to reproduce the error on CDH 5.3. Which CDH version are you using?

Comment: Okay.
Did you get this error as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778575/error-about-deployment-of-flink-on-yarn If yes, how did you resolve it?

Comment: i still get error when i run ~flink*0.9.0/bin/yarn-session.sh
 06:39:14,750 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
06:39:15,774 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

Comment: When you are getting this error, the HADOOP_CONF_DIR is not exported.
Just set the path and stuff should work

Comment: I did export the variable value in the session using command line, before the execution of flink run command. 

>export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn"
>echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn

Answer (score 1):

(I had a private conversation with the author of the original question to figure out this solution)

The log files posted in the comments of the original question indicate that the job was submitted against a standalone installation of Flink. Standalone Flink currently only supports accessing Kerberos secured HDFS if the user is authenticated on all worker nodes.
With Flink on YARN, only the user starting the job on YARN needs to be authenticated with Kerberos.

Also, in the comment section, there was another issue:

```
robert@cdh544-worker-0:~/hd22/flink-0.9.0$ ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 2
20:39:50,563 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy                         - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
20:39:50,600 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         - Using values:
20:39:50,602 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -  TaskManager count = 2
20:39:50,602 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -  JobManager memory = 1024
20:39:50,602 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -  TaskManager memory = 1024
20:39:51,708 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
20:39:52,710 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
20:39:53,712 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
20:39:54,714 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client                                  - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

The problem is that you are using Flink 0.9.0 (with Hadoop 2.2.0 included) on a cluster with Hadoop/YARN 2.6.0 with YARN HA enabled.
Flink's old (2.2.0) Hadoop library is not able to properly read the ResourceManager address for a HA setup.

Downloading Flink (with Hadoop 2.6.0) will make it work.

Comment: Thanks so much Robert. Sorry I missed to comeback and acknowledge the fact that the issue was resolved with your help.

Comment: Great. If you want, you can also mark my response in stackoverflow as the correct answer. This way I'm getting 15 reputation points on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing might not be related to exporting HADOOP_CONF_DIR for making Hadoop configuration files visible to Flink but in the value of HADOOP_CONF_DIR itself!
If you used Cloudera Manager, please make sure that the location you are referring to is correct and does exist in all your nodes. 
Also, it is worth trying the following common location of Hadoop configuration files: /etc/hadoop/conf

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf

Comment: I was able to verify the HADOOP_CONF_DIR value path existed in all the nodes and also used the default value. Same issue..

However tried to define a local file directory for the output and when executed the same code i got a new issue along with Kerberos authentication (i think it could be due to the input file is in HDFS)
The new error got was

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Failed to submit job 673ea0d83bb42257d963a9198ed4e271 (WordCount Example)